# Tableview with sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, sections

I'm about to load a tableview with two sections.  The data will be coming from core data.  Would it be better to have them in two entities?  There are 10 rows in each section.
The sections will at a later stage grow to 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an NSDictionary with two NSArray (or NSMutableArray). That way you would avoid if clauses. :)